# Spring Boot DBRef is null after saving

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have `user` and `role` models. Thats look like this:

`User:`

```
@Document("user")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @DBRef
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

`Role:`

```
@Document("role")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

}
```

And I have besides others those three methods to save user, save role and add role to user, like this:

```
@Override
public User saveUser(User user) {
    log.info("Saving new user {} to the database", user.getName());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@Override
public Role saveRole(Role role) {
    log.info("Saving new role {} to the database", role.getName());

    return roleRepository.save(role);
}

@Override
public void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName) {
    log.info("Adding role {} to user {}", roleName, username);

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
    user.getRoles().add(role);
}
```

Also I have a `CommandLineRunner` to insert those data

```
 @Bean
CommandLineRunner run(UserService userService) {
    return args -> {
        userService.saveRole(new Role(null, "ROLE_USER"));
        userService.saveRole(new Role(null, "ROLE_ADMIN"));

        userService.saveUser(new User(null,"Stefan", "stefanadmin", "stefanadmin", new ArrayList<>()));
        userService.saveUser(new User(null,"Marko", "markoadmin", "markoadmin", new ArrayList<>()));
        userService.saveUser(new User(null,"Jovan", "jovanobicanuser", "jovanobicanuser", new ArrayList<>()));

        userService.addRoleToUser("stefanadmin", "ROLE_ADMIN");
        userService.addRoleToUser("stefanadmin", "ROLE_USER");
        userService.addRoleToUser("markoadmin", "ROLE_ADMIN");
        userService.addRoleToUser("jovanobicanuser", "ROLE_USER");


    };
}
```

And everything works fine except `array column roles`, its empty.

Its like this in JSON when I try to return all users:

```
{"id":"6331bda42c1fa17e41079c99","name":"Jovan","username":"jovanobicanuser","password":"jovanobicanuser","roles":[]}]
```

I'm following some tutorial for this stuff, guy is using MySql while I'm using Mongo, so I think problem is somewhere how I'm trying to connect those two tables.

What can cause problem like this, what I'm missing?

Comment: in the definition of `addRoleToUser` method, you forgot to save that user do db.

Comment: Aghhh I see it now, thank you so much